# onmouseout conflicting with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseout

Ok, I am using JavaScript to control an image swap so that when someone clicks on the image, it changes to a "lit" version of the image. The code to do this within the link tag is `onclick="changeto('wdl')"` and I added `onmouseover="changeto('wdl')"` to the link so when you hover over it, it lights up as well.

Now, where the problem comes in, naturally, is when I added `onmouseout="changeto('wdd')"` which is the unlit version of the image. What happens here of course is when I hover over it, it lights up, when I move the cursor away it changes to the non lit version. But when you click on it it changes the image to the lit version as it should, but because of the `onmouseout` command, it changes to the unlit version.

What I want is to be able to hover on the image and have it light up. If you click it and move the mouse away it stays lit, but if you don't click it and move the mouse away it stays on the "off" image.

Any help appreciated, I am stumped here. I was going to try to use some sort of `if (!this)` type of thing, but I honestly just don't know.

Comment: Some example code may greatly assist in giving the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I see two solutions:
1. Declare separate CSS class for `onclick` event that is defined below `wdd` (or uses `!important`.
2. Use a flag variable which is set to `true` in `onclick` and then tested in `onmouseout`:</strike>

```
onclick="changeto('wdl');flag=true;" 
onmouseout="if (!flag) changeto('wdd')"
```

Here is a simple example with CSS and Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Example</title>
        <style>
            #whl {
                background: #e0e0ff;
                line-height: 150px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 150px;
            }
            #wdl {
                background: #e0ffe0;
                line-height: 150px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 150px;
            }
            #whl:hover {
                background: #ffcccc;
            }
            #wdl:hover {
                background: #ffcccc;
            }
            #whl.selected {
                background: #ffcccc;
            }
            #wdl.selected {
                background: #ffcccc;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function doClick(el) {
                document.getElementById("whl").className = document.getElementById("whl").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)selected(?!\S)/ , '' );
                document.getElementById("wdl").className = document.getElementById("wdl").className.replace( /(?:^|\s)selected(?!\S)/ , '' );
                el.className += "selected";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="whl" onclick="doClick(this);">WHL</div>
        <div id="wdl" onclick="doClick(this);">WDL</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works with colours and in your case you will have to replace colours with background images (in the CSS).

Comment: Yes. Declare a global variable `flag` and set it to `false` initially. It is a bad practise, but without the code I can't really suggest anything better.

Comment: I looked through your code and I couldn't find an obvious solution.
I would go with @josnidhin solution - using different CSS classes and Javascript for clicks, but this will require rewriting substantial part of your page.

Comment: Now that I am actually attempting to put this in to my coding, does this do the onclick as well? What does the .selected do if I may ask? Since I have to do this for all three of those slider buttons I just want to understand what is happening so I do it right :)

Comment: First, for every element you declare two CSS classes - regular one and `:hover` one. That way you will have nice transitions when user moves the mouse over. Next, you declare `selected` CSS class for an element that user clicks on. What the Javascript code does is basically removes `selected` class from all the elements and then adds it to the one that was clicked. It is important that `selected`  be declared AFTER all the other. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes. As I said, it will require some changes.

Comment: Ok, one more bump in the road, if you go to www.djcproductions.net, it works for the clicking but not the hovering, but if you got to www.djcproductions.net/test.html, it works completely, I literally copy and pasted from test.html to my index.html- any thoughts as to why it works in one and not the other? I even loaded them both up in dreamweaver into live mode where they both worked, but in a browser, only test.html works?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of CSS and javascript. Look up css hover to achieve the mouseover function and do the click part from js

CSS Hover on w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp